# How change the font of attributed string in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have added attributed string on label.I am displaying html text which works fine but by default it is always showing Times new roman family. Please tell how can i change text family.

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[inst.desc dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: The fastest way would be to edit the `inst.desc` and add it there in HTML format style. Else, you would have to enumerate the whole attributed string for NSFontAttributeName.

Comment: not able to set html content in ur code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with this:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[inst.desc dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
NSMutableAttributedString *newString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedString];
NSRange range = (NSRange){0,[newString length]};
[newString enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:range options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
    UIFont *replacementFont =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Roman" size:14.0];
    [newString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:replacementFont range:range];
}];
self.label.attributedText = newString;
```

Comment: Yes, you should add this after the allocation of the attributed string.  Check my edited answer

Comment: UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Roman" size:14.0]; is my font it's font issue

Comment: I can't understand what is your problem.

Comment: I have added UIfont but    [newString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:replacementFont range:range]; showing error of font

Comment: What error is showing?

Comment: If there is bold or italic effect, this will "delete" it.

Answer (score 5):

you can do like that:

```
NSDictionary *attrDict = @{
    NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:Arial size:16.0],
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]
};
 NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"string" attributes:attrDict];
```